# Train neural network: Mathematical reason for Nan due to batch size

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, nan

I am training a CNN. I use Googles pre-trained [inceptionV3](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/inception) with a replaced last layer for classification. During training, I had a lot of issues with my cross entropy loss becoming **nan**.After trying different things (reducing learning rate, checking the data etc.) it turned out the **training batch size** was too high.

Reducing training batch size from 100 to 60 solved the issue. Can you provide an explanation why too high batch sizes cause this issue with a cross entropy loss function? Also is there a way to overcome this issue to work with higher batch sizes (there is a paper suggesting batch sizes of 200+ images for better accuracy)?

Answer (score 5):

Larger weights (resulting exploding gradients) of the network produces skewed probabilities in the soft max layer. For example, **[0 1 0 0 0 ]** instead of **[0.1 0.6 0.1 0.1 0.1]**. Therefore, produce numerically unstable values in the cross entropy loss function.

```
cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y_))
```

when y_ = 0,  cross_entropy becomes infinite (since 0*log(0)) and hence **nan**.

The main reason for weights to become larger and larger is the **exploding gradient** problem. Lets consider the gradient update,

**∆wij = −η ∂Ei/ ∂wi**

where **η** is the learning rate and **∂Ei/∂wij** is the partial derivation of the loss w.r.t weights. Notice that **∂Ei/ ∂wi** is the average over a mini-batch **B**. Therefore, the gradient will depend on the mini-batch size **|B|** and the learning rate **η**.

In order to tackle this problem, you can reduce the learning rate. As a rule of thumb, its better to set the initial learning rate to zero and increase by a really small number at a time to observe the loss.

Moreover, Reducing the mini batch size results in increasing the variance of stochastic gradient updates. This sometimes helps to mitigate **nan** by adding noise to the gradient update direction.

Comment: Thanks for our answer Nipun (upvote). I am especially interested in the effect of the batch size (mathematically). Can you provide a few more details on that?

Comment: I am also facing the problem of gradient explosion when increasing batch size. Your answer makes sense to me, but what's your comment on this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53033556/how-should-the-learning-rate-change-as-the-batch-size-change , which suggests setting learning rate proportional to batch size?